# Separating text from lines

Tags: tables

I'm using

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulewidth=0.7pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|c|c|c|l|}
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & fun &  &  &  & first sight \\
1 & for & nothing &  & 5 & at & university \\
 &  & a chance &  &  &  & expense \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & chance &  &  &  & control \\
2 & by & mistake &  & 6 & under & (her) breath \\
 &  & accident &  &  &  & investigation \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & holiday &  &  &  & touch \\
3 & on & business &  & 7 & out of & luck \\
 &  & a diet &  &  &  & work \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & trouble &  &  &  & A to Z \\
4 & in & a mess &  & 8 & from & scratch \\
 &  & the end &  &  &  & memory \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

In the third column, the first words are very close to the lines. Is there a way to separate a bit those words from the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION:**

It is neither pretty nor automatic, but here I add a 3pt buffer (above and below) the top word in each row with `\addstackgap`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{3pt}
\begin{document}

\arrayrulewidth=0.7pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|c|c|c|l|}
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  &  \addstackgap{fun} &  &  &  & first sight \\
1 & for & nothing &  & 5 & at & university \\
 &  & a chance &  &  &  & expense \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & \addstackgap{chance} &  &  &  & control \\
2 & by & mistake &  & 6 & under & (her) breath \\
 &  & accident &  &  &  & investigation \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & \addstackgap{holiday} &  &  &  & touch \\
3 & on & business &  & 7 & out of & luck \\
 &  & a diet &  &  &  & work \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & \addstackgap{trouble} &  &  &  & A to Z \\
4 & in & a mess &  & 8 & from & scratch \\
 &  & the end &  &  &  & memory \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ALTERNATE APPROACH**

An alternative solution to avoid need to alter each row data.  Add a custom strut in the column definition.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\def\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{10pt}}
\begin{document}

\arrayrulewidth=0.7pt
\begin{tabular}{@{\mystrut}|c|c|l|c|c|c|l|}
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  &   fun &  &  &  & first sight \\
1 & for & nothing &  & 5 & at & university \\
 &  & a chance &  &  &  & expense \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & chance &  &  &  & control \\
2 & by & mistake &  & 6 & under & (her) breath \\
 &  & accident &  &  &  & investigation \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & holiday &  &  &  & touch \\
3 & on & business &  & 7 & out of & luck \\
 &  & a diet &  &  &  & work \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  & trouble &  &  &  & A to Z \\
4 & in & a mess &  & 8 & from & scratch \\
 &  & the end &  &  &  & memory \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `\extrarowheight` from the `array` package.

While the eye measures the distance from the bottom words to the rule by looking at the baseline, when it comes to the top, we look at ascenders. Some easy geometry allows us to compute the necessary extra height.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{%
  \dimexpr\dp\strutbox-\ht\strutbox+\fontcharht\font`A
}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|c|c|c|l|}
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
  &     & fun      &&   &        & first sight \\
1 & for & nothing  && 5 & at     & university \\
  &     & a chance &&   &        & expense \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
  &     & chance   &&   &        & control \\
2 & by  & mistake  && 6 & under  & (her) breath \\
  &     & accident &&   &        & investigation \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
  &     & holiday  &&   &        & touch \\
3 & on  & business && 7 & out of & luck \\
  &     & a diet   &&   &        & work \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
  &     & trouble  &&   &        & A to Z \\
4 & in  & a mess   && 8 & from   & scratch \\
  &     & the end  &&   &        & memory \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a different realization:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{llcll}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{4-5}
1. \textit{for} & fun      && 5. \textit{at}     & first sight \\
                & nothing  &&                    & university \\
                & a chance &&                    & expense \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{4-5}
2. \textit{by}  & chance   && 6. \textit{under}  & control \\
                & mistake  &&                    & (her) breath \\
                & accident &&                    & investigation \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{4-5}
3. \textit{on}  & holiday  && 7. \textit{out of} & touch \\
                & business &&                    & luck \\
                & a diet   &&                    & work \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{4-5}
4. \textit{in}  & trouble  && 8. \textit{from}   & A to Z \\
                & a mess   &&                    & scratch \\
                & the end  &&                    & memory \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{4-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set some form of `\minrowclearance{<len>}`, which increases the gap between the cell contents and horizontal rules to at least `<len>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength{\minrowclearance}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.7pt}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|c|c|c|l|}
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    &     & fun      &  &   &        & first sight \\
  1 & for & nothing  &  & 5 & at     & university \\
    &     & a chance &  &   &        & expense \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    &     & chance   &  &   &        & control \\
  2 & by  & mistake  &  & 6 & under  & (her) breath \\
    &     & accident &  &   &        & investigation \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    &     & holiday  &  &   &        & touch \\
  3 & on  & business &  & 7 & out of & luck \\
    &     & a diet   &  &   &        & work \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    &     & trouble  &  &   &        & A to Z \\
  4 & in  & a mess   &  & 8 & from   & scratch \\
    &     & the end  &  &   &        & memory \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...consider looking into presenting tables using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).