# Thickness control on vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: tables, rules

Regarding [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295506/separating-text-from-lines) example, having now:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulewidth=0.7pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|c|c|c|l|}
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  &  &  &  &  &   \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &   \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &   &  \\
 &  &   &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
 &  &  &  &  &  &   \\
 &  &   &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &   &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The command `\arrayrulewidth=0.7pt` controls the thickness for both vertical and horizontal lines, but now I want to reduce the thickness of the inner lines (both vertical and horizontal), and keep the thickness of the external lines.

---

I wanted to add color to the table but I couldn't. I used `\arrayrulecolor{[color here]}` but in only colored the inner lines, and I want to color the whole table.

Comment: Why are you drawing two tables in one?

Comment: Ah, it's just because I wanted to put two ones together and then I created a space between those.

Comment: Just it would be a lot easier if they were 2 rather than 1.

Comment: Can you provide an answer then as an optional way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [you requested it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295559/thickness-control-on-vertical-and-horizontal-lines/295806#comment715573_295559), here's a solution for a split version of the table i.e. 2 tables rather than 1. Here, we remove the outer lines from the `tabular` specifications and wrap them in boxes. `efbox` allows us to specify the rule colour, line width and margin. To make the box fit closely, eliminating any gap between the rules and the table, we set the margin to zero. The line width is then set to `0.7pt` and `\arrayrulewidth` can be left as default or altered as desired. All we need do is set the colours of the box rules and the `\arrayrulecolor` to the colour(s) we desire. Here, I use a shade of blue.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{efbox}
\efboxsetup{linecolor=blue!75!black, linewidth=.7pt, margin=0pt}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{blue!75!black}
\efbox{\begin{tabular}{c|c|l}
  &  &       \\
  &  &      \\
  &  &     \\
  \hline
  &  &       \\
  &  &      \\
  &  &     \\
  \hline
  &  &      \\
  &  &      \\
  &  &     \\
  \hline
  &  &       \\
  &  &     \\
  &  &     \\
\end{tabular}}
\efbox{\begin{tabular}{c|c|l}
  &  &       \\
  &  &      \\
  &  &     \\
  \hline
  &  &       \\
  &  &      \\
  &  &     \\
  \hline
  &  &      \\
  &  &      \\
  &  &     \\
  \hline
  &  &       \\
  &  &     \\
  &  &     \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2 tables in 2 boxes]

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use  the `boldline` package: here is an example with 1pt thicklines:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{boldline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{V{2.5}c|c|lV{2.5}cV{2.5}c|c|lV{2.5}}
  \clineB{1-3}{2.5}\clineB{5-7}{2.5}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\[-1pt]
  \clineB{1-3}{2.5}\clineB{5-7}{2.5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For coloured lines, it doesn't work. I only can propose a workaround with `hhline`, colouring double line and the space between the lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, colortbl, xcolor, hhline}

\begin{document}

\setlength\doublerulesep{0.2pt}\arrayrulecolor{red}\doublerulesepcolor{red}
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{red}\vrule width1pt}c|c|l!{\color{red}\vrule width1pt}c!{\color{red}\vrule width1pt}c|c|l!{\color{red}\vrule width1pt}}
  \hhline{|===|>{\arrayrulecolor{white}\doublerulesepcolor{white}}~>{\arrayrulecolor{red}\doublerulesepcolor{red}}|:===|}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \\
  \hhline{===>{\arrayrulecolor{white}\doublerulesepcolor{white}}~%
  >{\arrayrulecolor{red}\doublerulesepcolor{red}}|:===}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! I see. The colour  problem is harder, as I once tried  to patch `\hlineB`, and it didn't work. But I'm not a LaTeX guru…

Comment: @Ustanak: I've added a workaround for colour, based on `hhline`.

Comment: It is not really hard, but it's lengthy for sure.